# how to slide set of divs using css javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i'm creating an image gallery so i want to slide my thumbnails (div) on clicking on div

```
<div id="pagecontnt">
    <div id="albumname"></div>
    <!--albumname-->
    <div id="imgewer"></div>
    <!--imgewer-->
    <div id="otherabms"></div>
    <!--otherabms-->
    <div id="thumbnailbox">
        <div onclick="putinframe('images/album01/cover1.jpg')"></div>
        <div onclick="putinframe('images/album01/cover2.jpg')"></div>
        <div onclick="putinframe('images/album01/cover3.jpg')"></div>
        <div onclick="putinframe('images/album01/cover4.jpg')"></div>
        <div onclick="putinframe('images/album01/cover5.jpg')"></div>
        <div onclick="putinframe('images/album01/homebaner1.jpg')"></div>
        <div onclick="putinframe('images/album01/homebaner2.jpg')"></div>
        <div onclick="putinframe('images/album01/homebaner3.jpg')"></div>
        <div onclick="putinframe('images/album01/homebaner4.jpg')"></div>
        <div onclick="putinframe('images/album01/homebaner5.jpg')"></div>
    </div>
    <!--thumbnailbox-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ajax_get_json('images/album01')
    </script>
</div>
<!--pagecontnt-->
```

so i want to slide that set of this  divs on clicking div

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: What's the issue here? From your HTML and the `putinframe()` things ... to me looks like you've stolen this HTML from somewhere and you don't know what to do now. Have you tried already to write some JavaScript to achieve your goal?

Comment: *'on clicking on div'* ... great! You could not be more descriptive ;)

Comment: If by clicking on div you mean your `thumbnailbox` div then you will run into possible trouble. You are not showing any CSS for this markup but since every child div is clickable by them self you will only be able to click the parent div in-between these child divs (if there is any space beween them at all). Besides from that a slide is fairly simple to achieve by using jQuery and anim(). Even vanilla JavaScript is pretty straightforward as well.